# Changing default view mode in Firefox to Desktop

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

Using Firefox Mobile for Android. I want to lock the option for Desktop mode on by default. The menu option only applies per-tab and is forgotten if I open a new tab.

I have looked around at extensions and in about:config without finding anything.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/addon/desktop-by-default/)?

Description:

> About this Add-on
>
> This add-on enables desktop mode by default; that is, "Request Desktop
>   Site" is always checked whenever opening a new tab. This is designed
>   for users with larger screens (primarily tablet users).
>
> NOTE: Make sure "Request Desktop Site" and/or Phony are disabled when
>   viewing this page; otherwise, you may not be able to see the install
>   button.

EDIT: Take [this tutorial](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57562109-285/permanently-request-desktop-sites-on-firefox-for-android/) you can:

1. In the Firefox address bar, type "about:config" and press Enter.
2. Tap the "Add a New Setting" button, then select "String" as the type.
3. For name, enter "general.useragent.override."
4. For value, enter the browser user agent string you want to use. You can do a Google search for the user agent strings of your preferred browser and OS. In this example, we're using the user agent string for the desktop version of Firefox 17 on Windows 7.

   > Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101
   >   Firefox/17.0
5. Restart Firefox and confirm that Web sites are loading the desktop versions.
   That's it. If you want to change the user agent later, go back to about:config and search for "general.useragent.override." Hit the Modify button to change the user agent or the Reset button to remove it.

Comment: It does not work. Still defaults to Mobile. With Firefox 21.

Comment: See my edits. There is an alternate approach you can try.

Comment: The method in the tutorial unfortunately does not manage to completely replicate the "desktop site" button. The scales of things will come out wrong and websites will be impossible to navigate. (See for example https://www.google.com/maps.) If I instead tick by hand the "desktop site" button it comes out much better. Some sources also tell to make an additional change to layout.css.devPixelsPerPx (see https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/p38p6t/guide_how_to_always_use_desktop_view_in_firefox/). Unfortunately that does not help either.

Comment: I made the question in my above comment into a new question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/250347/changing-default-view-mode-in-firefox-exactly-to-the-equivalent-of-the-desktop.